# Wrapper of my template is floating over my footer

Tags: html, css, xhtml

The problem is keeping when i place some ul links in my footer

can somebody help me with this problem its really bugging me and my deadline is in about 24 hours.

this is the link to the slice

http://mediafb59.fiftynine.axc.nl/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the margin-bottom css from your wrapper.

current css:

```
#wrapper {
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto 10px;
text-align: left;
min-height: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin-bottom: -130px;
}
```

fixed:

```
#wrapper {
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto 10px;
text-align: left;
min-height: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```